# How do I customize font styles in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

Google Docs provides several styles such as header 1, header 2, normal text, etc.

How do I customize these styles? I don't like the default color of light grey for header 4. I want it to be black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set the default header style to the text you need
2. Change the style to your liking
3. Select the restyled text if it's deselected
4. Click on the style button then on the arrow next to the heading level you want to restyle
5. In the menu, select `Update [style] to match selection`

[image]

Comment: Very simple and intuitive way, and allows you to change format in one shot for header  everywhere in the doc in case your format preference changes.